# Multidimensional array with array class error: too many initializers

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I try to declare a multidimensional array with:

```
array<array<int, 7>, 5> arrayOne = {
{1, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{2, 3, 8, 7, 7, 0, 0},
{3, 4, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0},
{4, 8, 7, 1, 4, 0, 0},
{5, 7, 6, 8, 3, 0, 0} };
```

I get:

```
|10|error: too many initializers for 'std::array<std::array<int, 7u>, 5u>'
```

But when I do the same with a standard [] array:

```
int arrayTwo[5][7]= {
{1, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{2, 3, 8, 7, 7, 0, 0},
{3, 4, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0},
{4, 8, 7, 1, 4, 0, 0},
{5, 7, 6, 8, 3, 0, 0} };
```

I get no errors. I am using mingw g++ on Windows 7 x64. I am new to c++ and stackoverflow, your patience is appreciated.

Comment: Did you want to use extra braces `{}` to deduce the `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't think I was using any extra braces, can you clarify where exactly they are?

Comment: _"can you clarify where exactly they are? "_ Did in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For initialization `std::array` slightly differs from raw arrays. `std::array` needs to see [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

You have to put extra braces that the initializer value can be deduced to a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 7>, 5> arrayOne = {
        { 
     // ^
          {1, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {2, 3, 8, 7, 7, 0, 0},
          {3, 4, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0},
          {4, 8, 7, 1, 4, 0, 0},
          {5, 7, 6, 8, 3, 0, 0} 
        }
     // ^
    };    
}
```

See [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caedc6bb45f052e0)